# Irrational to the Power of Irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

It is true that an irrational number to the power of an irrational number could be rational. I am curious about the following:

Are there conditions that imply irrational to the power of irrational will be rational ?

Comment: The pointer to the duplicate is mistaken. The first sentence is NOT a question, but is instead declarative (asserting the truth of the answers to the linked question!) The **second** sentence is a question that could actually use answering.

Answer (score 2):

We can find a class of examples using the fact that, for $k$ integer, $\ln k$ is irrational  (as a consequence of [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem)) and
$e^{\ln k}=k$ is rational.